# Problem filtering the minimum value of an array at the array input in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I wanted the food with the lowest price to be displayed on the console, but my code does not work. Thank you for helping me get the correct code.

Give me the output I want : name : Berger price : 23.83

```js
let menu = [
    { id: 1, name: "Soda", price: 3.12, size: "4oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 2, name: "Beer", price: 6.50, size: "8oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 3, name: "Margarita", price: 12.99, size: "12oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 4, name: "Pizza", price: 25.10, size: "60oz", type: "Food" },
    { id: 5, name: "Kebab", price: 31.48, size: "42oz", type: "Food" },
    { id: 6, name: "Berger", price: 23.83, size: "99oz", type: "Food" },
];

const cheap_food = () => {
    const cheap = menu.filter(menuItem => menuItem.price > 0 && menuItem.type === "Food");
    cheap.forEach(price => console.log(Math.min(price)));
}
cheap_food();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destructure the `price` from each **menuItem** object that you're getting. Even after `filter`, the `cheap` array is an array of **objects** and not just price values. With your **updated question**, following will work :-

```js
let menu = [
    { id: 1, name: "Soda", price: 3.12, size: "4oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 2, name: "Beer", price: 6.50, size: "8oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 3, name: "Margarita", price: 12.99, size: "12oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 4, name: "Pizza", price: 25.10, size: "60oz", type: "Food" },
    { id: 5, name: "Kebab", price: 31.48, size: "42oz", type: "Food" },
    { id: 6, name: "Berger", price: 23.83, size: "99oz", type: "Food" },
];


const cheap_food = () => {
    const cheap = menu.filter(menuItem => menuItem.price > 0 && menuItem.type === "Food");
        const item = cheap.sort((itemA,itemB)=>itemA.price-itemB.price)[0];
        console.log(`${item.name} price : ${item.price}`);
}
cheap_food();
```

Comment: This is not my answer
My desired result      name : Berger price : 23.83

Comment: @Amir7222 Seems you updated your question.

Comment: Yes, please help me to reach a conclusion

Comment: @Amir7222 The above can be done with `.forEach` as well. It's just `.sort` seemed cleaner to me.

Comment: What should I do if I want to show the largest number?

Comment: `const item = cheap.sort((itemA,itemB)=>itemA.price-itemB.price)[cheap.length-1]`. Our sort implementation returns an array where elements are sorted in increasing order. So first element (`index = 0`) is smallest and last element (`index = length of array - 1`) is the greatest.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `price.price` instead of only price. The reason for that is that the `filter` function returns the filtered object. Therefore you need to wether destructure your object or access the price directly.